# How I can search pattern in multiple text file and write in to new multiple text file also

Tags: python, regex, file, text-extraction

```
import re
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('10.123.130*.txt')
pattern = re.compile(r"^\S+ \S+ \S+ 205\d+.*$")

extract_on = False
extracts_eds_upe = []


for fileName in list_of_files:
   with open(fileName, 'r') as myfile:
      print(myfile)
      #lines = myfile.readlines()
      for line in myfile:
          if pattern.search(line) :
             extract_on = True
             extracts_eds_upe.append((line.rstrip('\n')))

      with open(os.path.join(r'D:\Python Project\DRP\UPE', os.path.basename(fileName)), 'w') as mytext:
          for line in extracts_eds_upe :
             mytext.write("undo ")
             mytext.write(line)
             mytext.write('\n')
```

---------Input file#1 ----------

```
#
FTP server-source -i LoopBack0
FTP client-source -i LoopBack0
#
info-center loghost source LoopBack0
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.97 205148001 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205148003 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205148003 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.24.165 205495401 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205495403 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205495403 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.53 205145401 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205145403 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205145403 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.49 213145001 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 213145003 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 213145003 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
#
```

---------Input file#2 ----------

```
#
FTP server-source -i LoopBack0
FTP client-source -i LoopBack0
#
info-center loghost source LoopBack0
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.85 205148001 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205148003 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205148003 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.24.16 205495401 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205495403 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205495403 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.49 213145001 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 213145003 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 213145003 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
#
```

---------Expect output file#1 ----------

```
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.97 205148001 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205148003 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205148003 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.24.165 205495401 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205495403 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205495403 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.53 205145401 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205145403 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205145403 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
```

---------Expect output file#2 ----------

```
mpls switch-l2vc 10.123.146.85 205148001 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205148003 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205148003 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
mpls switch-l2vc 10.124.24.16 205495401 tunnel-policy TE between 10.123.130.1 205495403 tunnel-policy TE backup 10.123.130.2 205495403 tunnel-policy TE encapsulation vlan
```

I have multiple text file and search pattern in file then write to the new file.But now the result in output multiple text are same , Actually should be not same .
Now the problem is when read text file and match pattern that target then write to new file then read to second file and match the pattern then write to file also , but when write to second file have patrern from second file append from first  I don't want like this I want to separate result pattern in each file output,anybody can help me please.

Comment: Indent the last 5 lines of your code. That will solve your problem

Comment: Hi , DarkKnight  I thik is not match of my requirement , Can u see of my input and output file , please... thank you.

Comment: The way your code is presented means that you will only ever get one output file. Look again at the indentation

Comment: Hi ,Darknight now I update my code for write output file. please help me to check again ,because code can run and write in multiple file but the result of second file is append from the first file ,I would like to separate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just slightly modified your code, please look, it should work.

```py
import re
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('10.123.130*.txt')
pattern = re.compile(r"^\S+ \S+ \S+ 205\d+.*$")

for fileName in list_of_files:
   with open(fileName, 'r') as myfile:
      print(myfile)
      # Moved inside the loop.
      extract_on = False
      extracts_eds_upe = []

      for line in myfile:
          if pattern.search(line) :
             extract_on = True
             extracts_eds_upe.append((line.rstrip('\n')))

      # Moved inside the loop.
      with open(os.path.join(r'D:\Python Project\DRP\UPE', os.path.basename(fileName)), 'w') as mytext:
          for line in extracts_eds_upe :
              mytext.write("undo ")
              mytext.write(line)
              mytext.write('\n')
```

Comment: Hi,Artem Mashkovskiy  as your suggest code now can read the first file and get output from that and for the second file now the code is infinity loop !!!. , I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hi,Artem Mashkovskiy  I have to update result the code is working now can match as my result , but the code is running long time about 5 mins , I just test read only 2 files each input file have about 20,000 lines , Is it normal time or not?  -- In my project should have 150 files. How we can optimize or fix it?

Comment: Hi, saratoon J. I just made a typo - added an extra indentation. Please, look at the edited answer.

Comment: Hi,Artem Mashkovskiy  after modify code running so fast. Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

One line resolver, FYI:

```
find . -type f -name "10.123.130*.txt" | xargs -I{} sh -c "grep -E '^\S+ \S+ \S+ 205\d+.*$' {} > {}.result"
```

Explanation:

1. `find . -type f -name "10.123.130*.txt"`, list all the matched file under the current directory.
2. `xargs -I{} sh -c`, split the `find` result by line and pass them to next `grep` one by one.
3. `grep -E '^\S+ \S+ \S+ 205\d+.*$'`, match the content by regex and output to stdout.
4. `> {}.result`, redirect the `grep` result to new file named source filename with `.result` suffix.

Enjoy it!